# Hand over a ListView item to next activity when clicked - best practice

Tags: listview

I'm a beginner and want something rather simple: I have Debt objects in a ListView, called from a SQLite database, and simply want to show more details about a Debt object, when it is clicked. Very simple, but I searched here and found complex solutions like putting the debtID into an Extra and query the database for the Debt with the ID in the next activity for all the details (its fields). Or with Serializeable. I have tried it, both worked. But please tell me: Why not simply make it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public static Debt selectedDebt = null;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        selectedDebt = (Debt) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShowDebtActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class ShowDebtActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_debt);

        TextView amountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        amountTextView.setText("Amount: " + MainActivity.selectedDebt.getAmount());
        //... for all details like amount, date, place, ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It works perfectly and is super easy compared to the solutions I found here, but is it for any reason bad practice? I am rather sure, it is bad practice :) Please tell me best practice for my purpose.